How to fix rtl-sdr usb_claim_interface error -6?
I tried to enter this command to the terminals
sudo rtl_fm -f 105900000

it returns this output
Found 1 device(s):
  0:  Realtek, RTL2838UHIDIR, SN: 00000001

Using device 0: Generic RTL2832U OEM
usb_claim_interface error -6
Failed to open rtlsdr device #0.

which caused me to cannot use the rtl-sdr properly
How can I solve this such an error?
If my information is not that clear please just ask.
Thank you

Just found the solution, that is if you're on linux, you have to setup rtl_sdr first. And if you still faced the same problem, there might be a software that currently using your rtl_sdr too at the same time.
